# Highcharts Activity gauge: series value formatter

Tags: javascript, highcharts

If y value is in large e.g: 5000000, the value display is an out-of-range so that I formatted it to millions like 5M. But, a highcharts value is not accepting the string value.

```
var num = 5000000;


function nFormatter(num) {
     if (num >= 1000000000) {
        return (num / 1000000000).toFixed(1).replace(/\.0$/, '') + 'G';
     }
     if (num >= 1000000) {
        return (num / 1000000).toFixed(1).replace(/\.0$/, '') + 'M';
     }
     if (num >= 1000) {
        return (num / 1000).toFixed(1).replace(/\.0$/, '') + 'K';
     }
     return num;
}

num = nFormatter(num);
..
..
..
..//highcharts

series: [{
        name: 'Move',
        data: [{
            color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0],
            radius: '112%',
            innerRadius: '88%',
            y: num //num value is 5M
        }]
    },
..
..
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the value to tooltip formatter function will resolve this.

```
..
..

tooltip: {
   formatter: function() {
      return num;
},
..
..
series: [{
   name: 'Move',
     data: [{
        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0],
        radius: '112%',
        innerRadius: '88%',
        y: parseInt(num)
    }]
},
..
..
```